# Editing items in a list pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list named Q395tenleastwords:

```py
[("'rising", 10), ("'childhood", 10), ("'lasted", 10),("'moore", 10), ("'drug", 10)]
```

I would like to edit the list so only the words remain, so the output is:

```py
['rising', 'childhood', 'lasted', 'moore', 'drug']
```

Could someone please help me with how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.lstrip` along with a `list` comprehension to retrieve the first element from each tuple:

```
>>> L = [("'rising", 10), ("'childhood", 10), ("'lasted", 10),("'moore", 10), ("'drug", 10)]
>>> words = [e[0].lstrip("'") for e in L]
>>> words
['rising', 'childhood', 'lasted', 'moore', 'drug']
```

This `str` method accepts multiple chars to remove from the ends, so if you wanted to strip out both single and double quotes from both ends of the string, I would suggest:

```
str.strip('"\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, `list comprehension` with `indexing` and `slicing`:

```
l = [("'rising", 10), ("'childhood", 10), ("'lasted", 10),("'moore", 10), ("'drug", 10)]

[x[0][1:] for x in l]
```

Output:

```
['rising', 'childhood', 'lasted', 'moore', 'drug']
```